# How do I convert a Date object to UTC without shifting the time?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, utc

Let's say I create a date object:

`new Date()`
`//Mon Sep 23 2019 17:16:37 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)`

How can I convert this to UTC, *without* shifting?

The result should be:

```
Mon Sep 23 2019 17:16:37 GMT-0000
```

Comment: How about using `moment.js`?

Comment: without shifting the time? you HAVE to shift the time `17:16:37 GMT-0000` is 7 hours earlier than `17:16:37 GMT-0700`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var d = new Date;
console.log(d.toString());
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - d.getTimezoneOffset())
console.log(d.toUTCString());
```

```js
var str = new Date().toString();
console.log(str);
str = str.replace(/\GMT[+-]\d+.*$/, 'GMT-0000')
console.log(str);
```

Though, another possible answer is, that you just want to change the string ... which is even simpler

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is just to set `GMT-0000` you can simply split on `GMT` and take the first element and add `GMT-0000`

```js
console.log(new Date().toString().split(/GMT/,1)[0] + 'GMT-0000')
```